# Trouble organizing dictionary by "key" values in descending order in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to organize a dictionary by "key" values and organizing the same list in descending order

ex.

```
d = {​22698705: [​['James', 'Howlett'],​ ​[2,9,7]]​ ​, ​38698705: [​['Jakie', ' chan'],​ ​[2,9,7]​]​,
​35698705: [​['Jean', 'Grey']​, ​[2,9,7]]​ ​}
```

the values would have to be organized in descending order and their given "values" would have to follow them in sequence (Ive been instructed to only use `.get()`, `.keys()`, `.values()`, and `.pop()`). The same list would have to print

```
{​22698705: [​['James', 'Howlett'],​ ​[2,9,7]]​, ​35698705: [​['Jean', 'Grey']​, ​[2,9,7]]​, 38698705: [​['Jakie', ' chan'],​ ​[2,9,7]​]​ ​}.
```

How can I do that with the conditions given?

Comment: From CPython 3.7 dictionaries __are__ order preserving, so are sortable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>>{k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items())}
{22698705: [['James', 'Howlett'], [2, 9, 7]], 35698705: [['Jean', 'Grey'], [2, 9, 7]], 38698705: [['Jakie', ' chan'], [2, 9, 7]]}
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately cant use .items() either. I was thinking about sorting key values into a list and sorting from there with respective values but i think it would just complicate things too much... any suggestion on how to do it without the .item()?

Comment: You mean putting keys into the list and then sorting the keys? If you put keys into the list then there wont be any relation to that list with the dictionary. 

`>>> l=[]
>>> l=[i for i in d]
>>> l
[22698705, 38698705, 35698705]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[22698705, 35698705, 38698705]`

Comment: I dont know how else i could manipulate the dictionary with the parameters given

Comment: [This](https://www.guru99.com/python-dictionary-beginners-tutorial.html) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I only have python 3.6.9 at hand, but this should do the trick :

```
>>> d = {22698705: [['James','Howlett'],[2,9,7]], 38698705:[['Jakie','chan'],[2,9,7]], 35698705:[['Jean','Grey'],[2,9,7]]}
>>> r = {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d)}
>>> r
{22698705: [['James', 'Howlett'], [2, 9, 7]], 35698705: [['Jean', 'Grey'], [2, 9, 7]], 38698705: [['Jakie', 'chan'], [2, 9, 7]]}
```